# How to resolve NullPointerException when using webservices in codename one

Tags: php, symfony, codenameone

i am calling a data from the database in php and pass the data to codename one using Webservices.
and to display itThis is my php code that I was calling in codename one
How to resolve NullPointerException when using webservices in codename one?

```
 /**
     * @Route("/liste", name="liste")
     */
    public function displayProduitMobile(NormalizerInterface $normalizer): Response
    {
        $produit = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Produit::class)->findAll();
        $jsonContent = $normalizer->normalize($produit, 'json', ['groups' => 'post:read']);
        return $this->render('mobile_produit/display.html.twig',
            ['data' => $jsonContent]);
    }
```

This is my Codename one code

```
public ArrayList<Produit> parseProduit(String jsonText){
        try {
            produit=new ArrayList<>();
            JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
            Map<String,Object> tasksListJson =
               j.parseJSON(new CharArrayReader(jsonText.toCharArray()));
           
            List<Map<String,Object>> list = (List<Map<String,Object>>)tasksListJson.get("root");
            for(Map<String,Object> obj : list){
                Produit t = new Produit();
                float id = Integer.parseInt(obj.get("id_Prod").toString());
                    t.setId_prod((int)id);
                    t.setNom(obj.get("nom").toString());     
                    t.setPrix(Float.parseFloat(obj.get("prix").toString()));     
                    t.setImage(obj.get("image").toString());     
                    t.setQuantite(Integer.parseInt(obj.get("quantite").toString()));     
                    t.setDescProd(obj.get("descProd").toString());
                    t.setIdCat(Integer.parseInt(obj.get("idCat").toString()));
                produit.add(t);
            }
           
           
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           
        }
        return produit;
    }
   
    public ArrayList<Produit> getAllProduits(){
        req = new ConnectionRequest();
        //String url = Statics.BASE_URL+"/tasks/";
        String url = Statics.BASE_URL+"/liste";
        System.out.println("===>"+url);
        req.setUrl(url);
        req.setPost(false);
        req.addResponseListener(new ActionListener<NetworkEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(NetworkEvent evt) {
                produit = parseProduit(new String(req.getResponseData()));
                req.removeResponseListener(this);
            }
        });
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);
        return produit;
    }
}
```

When I run my code, I was getting the error code below:

```
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager.addToQueueAndWait(NetworkManager.java:746)
[EDT] 0:0:3,297 - Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - -1
[EDT] 0:0:3,300 - Exception during JSON parsing at row: 1 column: 882 buffer: 
    at com.mycompany.services.ServiceProduit.getAllProduits(ServiceProduit.java:111)
[EDT] 0:0:3,319 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
[EDT] 0:0:3,330 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
    at com.mycompany.gui.ListProduitFrom.<init>(ListProduitFrom.java:29)
    at com.mycompany.gui.HomeForm.lambda$new$1(HomeForm.java:29)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1203)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.services.ServiceProduit.parseProduit(ServiceProduit.java:79)
    at com.mycompany.services.ServiceProduit$2.actionPerformed(ServiceProduit.java:107)
    at com.mycompany.services.ServiceProduit$2.actionPerformed(ServiceProduit.java:104)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:45)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher$CallbackClass.run(EventDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.executeSerialCall(Display.java:1395)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1379)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1321)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1503)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1542)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager.addToQueueAndWait(NetworkManager.java:746)
    at com.mycompany.services.ServiceProduit.getAllProduits(ServiceProduit.java:111)
    at com.mycompany.gui.ListProduitFrom.<init>(ListProduitFrom.java:29)
    at com.mycompany.gui.HomeForm.lambda$new$1(HomeForm.java:29)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1203)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.services.ServiceProduit.parseProduit(ServiceProduit.java:79)
    at com.mycompany.services.ServiceProduit$2.actionPerformed(ServiceProduit.java:107)
    at com.mycompany.services.ServiceProduit$2.actionPerformed(ServiceProduit.java:104)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:45)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher$CallbackClass.run(EventDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.executeSerialCall(Display.java:1395)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1379)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1321)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1503)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1542)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager.addToQueueAndWait(NetworkManager.java:746)
    at com.mycompany.services.ServiceProduit.getAllProduits(ServiceProduit.java:111)
    at com.mycompany.gui.ListProduitFrom.<init>(ListProduitFrom.java:29)
    at com.mycompany.gui.HomeForm.lambda$new$1(HomeForm.java:29)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1203)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: What's on line 79 in `ServiceProduit.java` ? Notice you can step over with a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: the seconde code is the cade of ServiceProduit.java

Comment: Yes but which line is line number 79 there? I can't count the lines since it's a partial class. Either way step over with a debugger and use the inspect feature to see which variable is null. You can place a breakpoint at line 79 and see which variable is causing the problem.